# how to find this trigonometric sum?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, binomial-theorem

$$\sum_{r=1}^{45} \tan^2(2r-1)°$$

I tried simplifying it to Cosecant terms and use complex numbers and binomial theorem...
I know the answer but not the solution so I can verify your answer once you post it... I am using the Euler form for Sin but then I am stuck..

Comment: I think it' another answer.